# How to merge remote master into remote test

Tags: git, merge

I have two remote branches Master and Test.

Master branch : A--B--C--D--E--F

Test branch : A--B--C--D

Changes were added to the master branch before being added to the test branch. The master branch is standing ahead of the test branch. How can I add changes in the master branch to the test branch? There is a solution for the opposite situation in the options.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening the context menu of the other branch?

Comment: You're showing commands that indicate that the active branch is `master`. Switch to `test` (that's the "Checkout" action), and you will see the other actions (merge something into `test`).

Comment: Thank you @LeGEC, I am new to git issues. I got the point and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git merge` needs to be run from the active branch.

From your screenshot : your current active branch is `master`, so the only actions that are offered are to merge something into `master`.

Switch to your `test` branch, you will then see actions offering to merge into `test`.